# Parsing image from XML Content

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, alamofire, swift5, xmlmapper

I am using  [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) for mapping XML response. Below is a few lines from the response I am getting from API URL,

```
<feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
<id>http://mzstoreservices-int.dslb.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=25/xml</id>
<title>iTunes Store: Top Songs</title>
<updated>2021-04-06T19:18:54-07:00</updated>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?cc=us&id=1&popId=1"/>
<link rel="self" href="http://mzstoreservices-int.dslb.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=25/xml"/>
<icon>http://itunes.apple.com/favicon.ico</icon>
<author>
<name>iTunes Store</name>
<uri>http://www.apple.com/itunes/</uri>
</author>
<rights>Copyright 2008 Apple Inc.</rights>
<entry>
<updated>2021-04-06T19:18:54-07:00</updated>
<id im:id="1547525311">https://music.apple.com/us/album/astronaut-in-the-ocean/1547525310?i=1547525311&uo=2</id>
<title>Astronaut In The Ocean - Masked Wolf</title>
<im:name>Astronaut In The Ocean</im:name>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://music.apple.com/us/album/astronaut-in-the-ocean/1547525310?i=1547525311&uo=2"/>
<im:contentType term="Music" label="Music">
<im:contentType term="Track" label="Track"/>
</im:contentType>
<category im:id="18" term="Hip Hop/Rap" scheme="https://music.apple.com/us/genre/music-hip-hop-rap/id18?uo=2" label="Hip-Hop/Rap"/>
<link title="Preview" rel="enclosure" type="audio/x-m4a" href="https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview124/v4/81/b4/95/81b495ac-0475-928b-8a27-a4fe2682749b/mzaf_17183909416838915149.plus.aac.p.m4a" im:assetType="preview">
<im:duration>30000</im:duration>
</link>
<im:artist href="https://music.apple.com/us/artist/masked-wolf/1313094981?uo=2">Masked Wolf</im:artist>
<im:price amount="1.29000" currency="USD">$1.29</im:price>
<im:image height="55">https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/af/ef/ff/afefff15-b936-3cb7-9101-166f8501e71a/075679793102.jpg/55x55bb.png</im:image>
<im:image height="60">https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/af/ef/ff/afefff15-b936-3cb7-9101-166f8501e71a/075679793102.jpg/60x60bb.png</im:image>
<im:image height="170">https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/af/ef/ff/afefff15-b936-3cb7-9101-166f8501e71a/075679793102.jpg/170x170bb.png</im:image>
<rights>℗ 2021 Elektra Records LLC</rights>
<im:releaseDate label="June 7, 2019">2019-06-07T05:00:00-07:00</im:releaseDate>
<im:collection>
<im:name>Astronaut In The Ocean - Single</im:name>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://music.apple.com/us/album/astronaut-in-the-ocean-single/1547525310?uo=2"/>
<im:contentType term="Music" label="Music">
<im:contentType term="Album" label="Album"/>
</im:contentType>
</im:collection>
<content type="html"><table border="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td> <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr valign="top" align="left"> <td align="center" width="166" valign="top"> <a href="https://music.apple.com/us/album/astronaut-in-the-ocean/1547525310?i=1547525311&uo=2"><img border="0" alt="Masked Wolf - Astronaut In The Ocean artwork" src="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/af/ef/ff/afefff15-b936-3cb7-9101-166f8501e71a/075679793102.jpg/100x100bb.png" /></a> </td> <td width="10"><img alt="" width="10" height="1" src="http://r.mzstatic.com/images/spacer.gif" /></td> <td width="95%"> <b><a href="https://music.apple.com/us/album/astronaut-in-the-ocean/1547525310?i=1547525311&uo=2">Astronaut In The Ocean</a></b><br/> <a href="https://music.apple.com/us/album/astronaut-in-the-ocean-single/1547525310?uo=2">Astronaut In The Ocean - Single</a><br/> <a href="https://music.apple.com/us/artist/masked-wolf/1313094981?uo=2">Masked Wolf</a> <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular"> <br/> <b>Genre:</b> <a href="https://music.apple.com/us/genre/music-hip-hop-rap/id18?uo=2">Hip-Hop/Rap</a> <br/> <b>Price:</b> $1.29 <br/> <b>Release Date:</b> June 7, 2019 </font> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <font size="2" face="Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular"> &#169; ℗ 2021 Elektra Records LLC</font> </td> </tr> </table> </content>
</entry>
```

Used [Almofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for calling api,

```
import Alamofire
import XMLMapper

func fetchData() {
        AF.request(URL(string: "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=20/xml")!, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: []).responseData { (response) in
        do{
              let xmlDictionary = try XMLSerialization.xmlObject(with: response.data!) as? [String: Any]
               print(xmlDictionary!)
               let rssFeed = XMLMapper<SongFeed>().map(XMLObject: xmlDictionary)
               print(rssFeed?.entry?[0].image ?? "")
          } catch {
               print("Serialization error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
    }
}
```

Here is my model class,

```
import XMLMapper

class SongFeed : XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    var title : String?
    var entry : [Entry]?
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {
    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        entry <- map["entry"]
    }
}

class Entry : XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    var title : String?
    var link: URL?
    var image : URL?
    var name : String?
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {
    }
    
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        link <- (map["link"], XMLURLTransform())
        image <- (map["im:image"], XMLURLTransform())
        name <- map["im:name"]
    }
}
```

I am unable to fetch image URL from the <im:image> tag from the XML response. Also I am confused as there are three <im:image> tags with different height parameters, how can I fetch one of them? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map the `im:image` elements you need to use an array of custom object, since there are more than one and they contain an attribute. (`height`)

Following the same logic, to map the `link` elements you need to use an array of custom object also.

The model that will work may be something like this:

```
class SongFeed: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var title: String?
    var entry: [Entry]?
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        entry <- map["entry"]
    }
}

class Entry: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var title: String?
    var link: [Link]?
    var image: [Image]?
    var name: String?
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        link <- map["link"]
        image <- map["im:image"]
        name <- map["im:name"]
    }
}

class Link: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var title: String?
    var rel: String?
    var type: String?
    var href: URL?
    var assetType: String?
    var duration: Double?
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map.attributes["title"]
        rel <- map.attributes["rel"]
        type <- map.attributes["type"]
        href <- (map.attributes["href"], XMLURLTransform())
        assetType <- map.attributes["im:assetType"]
        duration <- map["im:duration"]
    }
}

class Image: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!
    
    var height: Int?
    var url: URL?
    
    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
    
    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        height <- map.attributes["height"]
        url <- (map.innerText, XMLURLTransform())
    }
}
```

Also, please notice the attributes mapping in the `mapping(map:)` function. It is clearly distinguished from element mapping.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It worked. (Y)